# javafx: How can I make TableCell Edit return double instead of string and the font changes color based on a condition?

Tags: java, javafx

I have the `Trade` object class with a

```
public class Trade {
    private DoubleProperty price;
    private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper caution;

    public Trade(double price){
        this.price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
        this.caution = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();
        this.caution.bind(this.volume.greaterThan(0));
    }   

    public double getPrice(){
        return this.price.get();
    }   

    public DoubleProperty priceProperty(){
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price.set(price);
    }
}
```

In my Controller class, I have the following `TableView` and `TableColumn`

**Problem is two-fold:**

1. The price property and price column only accepts `double`. But the EditingDoubleCell code below only return String. **How can I make it return double and all the `String`s the user typed in will be ignored?**
2. The second function I would like to have is that: the font within the cell of `Price` column (**talking about the same price cell**)  will change its color to blue when the `caution` property is true and to red when the `caution` property is false?

---

```
public class EditingDoubleCell extends TableCell<Trade,String>{

    private TextField textField;

    public EditingDoubleCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.requestFocus();
            //textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }


    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());

                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }

    private void createTextField(){

        Locale locale  = new Locale("en", "UK");
        String pattern = "###,###.###";
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
        df.applyPattern(pattern);
        //String format = df.format(123456789.123);
        //System.out.println(format);

        //NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();        
        textField = new TextField();

        // add filter to allow for typing only integer
        textField.setTextFormatter( new TextFormatter<>( c ->
        {
            if (c.getControlNewText().isEmpty()) {
                return c;
            }
            ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition( 0 );
            Object object = df.parse( c.getControlNewText(), parsePosition );

            if ( object == null || parsePosition.getIndex() < c.getControlNewText().length() )
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return c;
            }
        } ) );

        textField.setText( getString() );

        textField.setMinWidth( this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2 );

        // commit on Enter
        textField.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle( ActionEvent event )
            {
                commitEdit( textField.getText() );
            }
        } );

        textField.focusedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                    Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2 )
            {
                if ( !arg2 )
                {
                    commitEdit( textField.getText() );
                }
            }
        } );

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried EditingDoubleCell extends TableCell<Trade, Double> {...}

Comment: Yes. I tried but `textField.getText() ` returns a `String` not a double. So ` commitEdit( textField.getText() );` is giving me an error.

Comment: It's hard to understand all of things your EditingDoubleCell class does, but couldn't you just define your column's type as Number instead of Double, then replace new EditingDoubleCell() with `new TextFieldTableCell<Trade, Number>(new FormatStringConverter<Number>(df))` or `new TextFieldTableCell<Trade, Number>(new NumberStringConverter(new Locale("en", "UK"), "###,###.###"))`?

Comment: Use a `TextFormatter<Double>` with a `StringConverter<Double>` as well as the filter you have defined. Then you can use `textFormatter.getValue()` instead of `textField.getText()` to return a `Double`.

Comment: Hi @James_D, Can you put this into a code example please because I am not really following here.

Comment: Hi @James_D , would really appreciate it if you can provide an answer for this question. Thank you very much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the first part of the problem, you should create your `TextFormatter` as a `TextFormatter<Double>`. This makes the `valueProperty` of the `TextFormatter` into a `Property<Double>`, so you can commit your edits by calling `getValue()` on the formatter. You need to specify a `StringConverter<Double>` so that it knows how to go from text to a `Double`, and vice-versa. So this looks like:

```
        StringConverter<Double> converter = new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Double number) {
                return df.format(number);
            }

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String string) {
                try {
                    double value = df.parse(string).doubleValue() ;
                    return value;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return 0.0 ;
                }
            }

        };

        textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter,  0.0, c -> {
            if (partialInputPattern.matcher(c.getControlNewText()).matches()) {
                return c ;
            } else {
                return null ;
            }
        }) ;
```

I changed the filter here, because your filter was only matching a "complete" input. Since the filter is applied to every individual edit, you must allow "partial" input, such as `"100,"`. The filter you had would not allow this (for example). The filter in the version here uses a regular expression: you can tinker with this to get it right but I use

```
Pattern partialInputPattern = Pattern.compile(""[-+]?[,0-9]*(\\.[0-9]*)?");
```

which is pretty lenient with what it allows.

Now, instead of committing the edit directly when the user hits enter, just commit the edit when the value of the text formatter changes:

```
    // commit on Enter
    textFormatter.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        commitEdit(newValue);
    });
```

The whole cell class now looks like

```
public static class EditingDoubleCell extends TableCell<Trade,Double>{

    private TextField textField;
    private TextFormatter<Double> textFormatter ;

    private DecimalFormat df ;

    public EditingDoubleCell(String...styleClasses) {
        Locale locale  = new Locale("en", "UK");
        String pattern = "###,###.###";
        df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
        df.applyPattern(pattern);

        getStyleClass().addAll(styleClasses);
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(df.format(getItem()));
        setGraphic(null);
    }


    @Override
    public void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());

                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : df.format(getItem());
    }

    private void createTextField(){

        textField = new TextField();

        StringConverter<Double> converter = new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Double number) {
                return df.format(number);
            }

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String string) {
                try {
                    double value = df.parse(string).doubleValue() ;
                    return value;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return 0.0 ;
                }
            }

        };

        textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter,  0.0, c ->
        {
            if (c.getControlNewText().isEmpty()) {
                return c;
            }
            ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition( 0 );
            Object object = df.parse( c.getControlNewText(), parsePosition );

            if ( object == null || parsePosition.getIndex() < c.getControlNewText().length() )
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return c;
            }
        } ) ;

        // add filter to allow for typing only integer
        textField.setTextFormatter( textFormatter);

        textField.setText( getString() );

        textField.setMinWidth( this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2 );

        // commit on Enter
        textFormatter.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            commitEdit(newValue);
        });
    }
}
```

(I added the constructor parameter so it will work with the solution to your second question.)

The second part is answered elsewhere, but I would just create a `rowFactory` for your table that sets a CSS pseudoclass based on the state of the caution property:

```
PseudoClass caution = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("caution");

table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<Trade> row = new TableRow<>();

    ChangeListener<Boolean> cautionListener = (obs, wasCaution, isNowCaution) -> 
        row.pseudoClassStateChanged(caution, isNowCaution);

    row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldTrade, newTrade) -> {
        if (oldTrade != null) {
            oldTrade.cautionProperty().removeListener(cautionListener);
        }
        if (newTrade == null) {
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(caution, false);
        } else {
            row.pseudoClassStateChanged(caution, newTrade.isCaution());
            newTrade.cautionProperty().addListener(cautionListener);
        }
    });

    return row ;
});
```

Then just set a style class on the cell you want the style to change on (e.g. add the style class `"price-cell"` to the `EditingDoubleCell` you defined). Then you can just use a CSS stylesheet to change the style as you need, e.g.

```
.table-row-cell .price-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}

.table-row-cell:caution .price-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: blue ;
}
```

will make the text red for price cells in rows that do not have `caution` set, and make it blue in rows that do.

Here is the complete SSCCE:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class TradeTable extends Application {

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Trade> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        TableColumn<Trade, Integer> volumeCol = column("Volume", trade -> trade.volumeProperty().asObject());
        TableColumn<Trade, Double> priceCol = column("Price", trade -> trade.priceProperty().asObject());

        priceCol.setCellFactory(col -> new EditingDoubleCell("price-cell"));

        table.getColumns().add(volumeCol);
        table.getColumns().add(priceCol);

        PseudoClass caution = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("caution");

        table.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Trade> row = new TableRow<>();

            ChangeListener<Boolean> cautionListener = (obs, wasCaution, isNowCaution) -> 
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(caution, isNowCaution);

            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldTrade, newTrade) -> {
                if (oldTrade != null) {
                    oldTrade.cautionProperty().removeListener(cautionListener);
                }
                if (newTrade == null) {
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(caution, false);
                } else {
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(caution, newTrade.isCaution());
                    newTrade.cautionProperty().addListener(cautionListener);
                }
            });

            return row ;
        });

        table.getItems().addAll(createRandomData());

        Button button = new Button("Change Data");
        button.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().forEach(trade -> {
            if (rng.nextDouble() < 0.5) {
                trade.setVolume(0);
            } else {
                trade.setVolume(rng.nextInt(10000));
            }
            trade.setPrice(rng.nextDouble() * 1000);
        }));
        BorderPane.setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(button, new Insets(10));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, button, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("trade-table.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private  List<Trade> createRandomData() {
        List<Trade> trades = new ArrayList<>(50);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 50; i++) {
            int volume = rng.nextDouble() < 0.5 ? 0 : rng.nextInt(10000) ;
            double price = rng.nextDouble() * 10000 ;
            trades.add(new Trade(price, volume));
        }
        return trades ;
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static class Trade {
        private DoubleProperty price;
        private IntegerProperty volume ;
        private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper caution;

        public Trade(double price, int volume){
            this.price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
            this.volume = new SimpleIntegerProperty(volume);
            this.caution = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();
            this.caution.bind(this.volume.greaterThan(0));
        }   

        public double getPrice(){
            return this.price.get();
        }   

        public DoubleProperty priceProperty(){
            return this.price;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price){
            this.price.set(price);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty volumeProperty() {
            return this.volume;
        }

        public final int getVolume() {
            return this.volumeProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setVolume(final int volume) {
            this.volumeProperty().set(volume);
        }

        public final ReadOnlyBooleanProperty cautionProperty() {
            return this.caution.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public final boolean isCaution() {
            return this.cautionProperty().get();
        }


    }

    public static class EditingDoubleCell extends TableCell<Trade,Double>{

        private TextField textField;
        private TextFormatter<Double> textFormatter ;

        private Pattern partialInputPattern = Pattern.compile(
                "[-+]?[,0-9]*(\\.[0-9]*)?");

        private DecimalFormat df ;

        public EditingDoubleCell(String...styleClasses) {
            Locale locale  = new Locale("en", "UK");
            String pattern = "###,###.###";
            df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
            df.applyPattern(pattern);

            getStyleClass().addAll(styleClasses);
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(df.format(getItem()));
            setGraphic(null);
        }


        @Override
        public void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());

                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : df.format(getItem());
        }

        private void createTextField(){

            textField = new TextField();

            StringConverter<Double> converter = new StringConverter<Double>() {

                @Override
                public String toString(Double number) {
                    return df.format(number);
                }

                @Override
                public Double fromString(String string) {
                    try {
                        double value = df.parse(string).doubleValue() ;
                        return value;
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return 0.0 ;
                    }
                }

            };

            textFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter,  0.0, c -> {
                if (partialInputPattern.matcher(c.getControlNewText()).matches()) {
                    return c ;
                } else {
                    return null ;
                }
            }) ;

            // add filter to allow for typing only integer
            textField.setTextFormatter( textFormatter);

            textField.setText( getString() );

            textField.setMinWidth( this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2 );

            // commit on Enter
            textFormatter.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                commitEdit(newValue);
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

With the CSS code above in trade-table.css.

Comment: Hi @James_D, this is excellent answer. However, currently, there are 2 issues: (1) During edit, with the cursor at the end of the double (e.g. 9,999), when I backspace, i got stuck at 9,9 . It doesn't allow me to backspace anymore. (2) It doesn't allow me to type in minus sign.

Comment: Not sure why the minus sign was an issue. The first issue was because the filter you used (which I just copied into my answer) was really checking for something it could parse as a complete entry. Since the filter is applied on every edit, you need to be a bit more lenient than that, since the user must be allowed to have partial input (e.g. you must allow `1,`). Updated code to use a regex instead.

Comment: Hi @James_D, I am trying to represent the minus sign using brackets `(value)` by having `df.setNegativePrefix("(" + df.getPositivePrefix());` and `df.setNegativeSuffix(")");` in the code, but this fails. Do you know how could I achieve this ?

Comment: I think I've really spent enough time on your project here, and have certainly answered your original question (which is actually two questions). You can't really keep coming back and adding new requirements. You should either accept answers to the questions or not; it doesn't really matter. But the purpose of SO is not to provide free consulting.

Comment: Apologies.  I tried to solve the problem yesterday but in vain. I got a bit frustrated that's why I left the comment above. Really sorry about this.

Comment: Only wish I could give you more points!  Amply demonstrated what needs to be done!

Answer (score 6):

**the first part of the question**: You can try the following class (It worked for me):

```
     public class EditingDoubleCell extends TableCell<Trade, Double> {

        private TextField textField;

        public EditingDoubleCell() {
            textField = new TextField();
            textField.setOnAction(e -> commitEdit(Double.valueOf(textField.getText())));
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.requestFocus();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getString());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(Double newValue) {
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {

                Locale locale = new Locale("en", "UK");
                String pattern = "###,###.###";
                DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
                df.applyPattern(pattern);
                String s = df.format(getItem());
                setText(s);
                setGraphic(null);
              // set font of Price cell to a color
            TableRow<Trade> row = getTableRow();
            if (row.getItem().getCaution()) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue;");
            } else {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                    }
            }
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }

    }
```

**the second part of the question**: Just call `setcellfactory(...)` for caution column and you have to override the method `updateItem(...)`:

```
 cautionCol.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Trade, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(String.valueOf(item));
                //TableRow<Trade> row = getTableRow();
                if (item) {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue;");
                } else {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                }

            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Just want to ask why does it not accept negative values ?

Comment: I haven't that problem.

Comment: I mean when I edit the cell, it doesn't allow me to type me `-` sign. And it is not displaying the comma separators at all, which I specified in `df.applyPattern(pattern)`

Comment: How about the second part of the question ？ any ideas ？

Comment: Hi @Win.ubuntu, just want to ask do you mind combining those 2 parts into one piece of code, because ideally I would want to have `setCellFactory(EditingDoubleCell)`, and within `EditingDoubleCell`, it includes the `updateItem` you just updated. Thanks! And don't you need a listener on the table cell, since I want to listen on newly added items' `cautionProperty()` value and automatically set its font to different color ?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to combine them into one piece of code. every column has its own updateItem method.

Comment: So, I cannot have the `EditingDoubleCell` that returns a double and at the same time, tableCell Listener that changes the font colour when the value of the cell is greater than a certain number ? I cannot have these two things in `setCellFactory` or separately one in `setCellFactory` and the other in `setCellValueFactory` ?

Comment: if it is the same TableCell, yes it is possible to combine theme,

Comment: yes I am talking about the same tableCell. Adding a Iistener for `cautionProperty()` and when  `cautionProperty().getValue() = true` , then set  font of `Price` cell  to a color, when it is false, set font of `Price` cell to another color. Sorry if I have confused you, I mean the same cell on the `Price` column all the time.

Comment: I edited my answer. see `updateItem(...)` method in `EditingDoubleCell`  class

Comment: the problem is that,  if you do a change in caution column, the color will not change automatically

Comment: Sorry, it is important that the color change in response to a change in cautionProperty(). And now I can type String during edit.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, I did as follows:

```
SimpleDoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
price.setValue(Double.parseDouble(EditingDoubleCell().getString()));
ObservableValue<Double> g = price.asObject();
return g;
```

This method anticipates that you can parse your String into double.
Works for me, tell me if it helped :)